# Iphone dev : how can I get a result from google currency converter?

Tags: iphone, currency, converters

Sorry for my english ^^
I would know how I can have a result from the google converter tool for currency, available on http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=GBP for example.

I have already tried something like that :

```
    -(IBAction)getResponse:(id) sender{

     NSString *myURLString = @"http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=GBP";

     NSURL *myURL =  [NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];

     NSData *data = [NSData alloc];

     data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];


     if(data!=nil && data != ""){

          NSString *response = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data]]

          [label setText: response];

     }

     else [label setText:@"not working"];
}
```

But when I click on my button, the label does not have a text (it is like it is empty).
Am I doing something wrong ?
Is it possible what I want to do ?
Thank you very much for your futures answers !
Olivier.

Comment: You are aware that this will return a full HTML page. See this page which has a example on using the google converter API: http://oohhyeah.blogspot.com/2009/01/google-currency-conversion-api.html

Comment: NSLog your response and see what you get. Check if its an NSString, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah.. It is possible...
See the data that you are getting is an HTML file or can be treated as xml. Just parse that xml file and get the result. There ia lot of things in that file but you have to only extract

```
<div id=currency_converter_result>1 USD = <span class=bld>0.6118 GBP</span>
```

Hey try this URL 
http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?INR

This URL will return the JSON

{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "44.5097254 Indian rupees",error: "",icc: true}

Just parse it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try...

> NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];

Then check you've got something in response

```
NSLog(@"%@", response);
```

Better yet, remove the NSData alloc/init

Replace with

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
```

And, you'll need to parse the return result, because you're not going to get back what you expect. Response will contain HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

You better use an asynchronous request to avoid blocking your app. Easy using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/):

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=GBP"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}


- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];



   [label setText: responseString];

}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error]; //you can log the error description

   [label setText:@"not working"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *myURLString = @"http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=1&from=USD&to=GBP";

NSURL *myURL =  [NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];

NSData *data = [NSData alloc];

data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];


if(data!=nil){

    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",response);
}
```

***Try this.
This API is giving HTML responce.***